# Are there dry yeasts that rival liquids for IPA's?

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters

My HBS just raised the prices of various liquid yeasts. Are there dry yeasts that are as good for IPA's? Recommendations please & should they be pitched dry or as a starter?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Danstar BRY-97 is a great option for American-style IPAs. It starts out kind of rough, but if you give it enough time to condition, it makes an amazing beer.

Fermentis Safale US-05 and Danstar Nottingham also a popular choices for American-style IPAs. You should ferment them at the low end of their temperature ranges.

For English-style IPAs, you can use Safale S-04, or Danstar Windsor Ale (I haven't used it).  You can also try to ferment at the high end of the range with US-05 (will give you some apricot-type notes).

It is hard to say whether any dry strain "rivals" a liquid strain because they have different characteristics in order to be able to be dried even if they originally come from the same source. But they *do* come from same sources as liquid yeast (e.g., WLP001, Wyeast 1056, US-05, and Bry-97 all come from the "Chico" strain, aka Sierra Nevada).

In terms of a starter, it is not advisable to make a starter with dry yeast. One pack should be OK to pitch into a moderate-gravity beer. If you need a higher cell count, pitch two packs of dry yeast -- dry yeast is cheap.

Comment: For an on-style IPA, I'd recommend 2 packets of dry, just to be sure. Safale's US-05 is Chico, but it's known to not floc out as soon as the liquid equivalent, for whatever reason. Also, there's a new line of dry yeasts called "Mangrove Jacks", and they've got a strain called "US West Coast Ale" that's supposed to be perfect for hoppy American beers.

Comment: These are all opinions, not facts.

Comment: True. The question itself calls for opinion, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

US-05 (= Wyeast1056, = WLP001) is a pretty good option for IPAs.

Dry yeast should be rehydrated, but the higher cell count generally means you don't need a starter.